# How to Create a Sidebar with Multiple Controller Methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller, sidebar

I have multiple controllers that I want to pull some of their methods into my sidebar:

```
habits_controller
goals_controller
valuations_controller
quantifieds_controller
users_controller
```

How can I do this without getting an undefined method error?

I tried creating a sidebar_controller, but what should I include in their to make it work?

Let's focus on habits as an example and then I could apply the lessons I learned it to the other controllers on my own.

Excerpt from **_sidebar.html.erb**

```html
<div id="sidebarheadingtop" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Today</b></h5></div>
 <% @habits.each do |habit| %>
       <td><%= raw habit.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></td>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**habits_controller**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
      @habits = current_user.habits
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if  @habit.save
        redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :target, :positive, :negative, :tag_list, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

**sidebar_controller**

```html
class SidebarController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @habits = current_user.habits
  end
end
```

I'm still a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you =]

**Github**: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly: you wish to take methods from various controllers and then call upon these methods within a sidebar controller.

This would seem to me to be going against convention and sounds a bit odd.  You shouldn't call on a controller's methods from another controller, if you wish to make your application *restful*.

If you wish to *mix-in* methods across multiple controllers (write a method once and then mix that method into a bunch of controllers so that all those controllers have their own copy of the method) then take that shared method and put it into a **concern**, then `include` that concern into your controller.  In your case: `include` that module into your sidebar controller.

**`app/controllers/concerns/shared.rb`**

```
module Shared
    def someMethod
        @someVariableToPassToView = 33
    end
end
```

**`app/controllers/sidebar_controller.rb`**

```
include Shared
# Your shared controller has now mixed in all the methods from within the 
# Shared module ( in this case, the someMethod method)
```

And of course don't forget to create the corresponding view to match sidebar's mixed in method: `someMethod`:

***app/views/sidebar/someMethod.html.erb***

```
<p> Outputting the contents of the variable someVariableToPassToView </p>
<p><%= @someVariableToPassToView<%></p>
```

Also, don't forget to update your **routes.rb** file for the actions you are mixing into sidebar so that Rails will know how to get to the appropriate view file:

```
get 'sidebar/somemethod'
```

To respond to your question: when we want to make an variable from a controller available to a view, we pass it as an instance variable.  That is what the `@` is for, to make this variable an instance variable so that we can pull out its contents from the view using the `<%= %>` notation.  This is what I did above as an example to pull the number 33 out of the variable it is stored in:  `@someVariableToPassToView`

I would highly recommend the following for you:

Watch Kevin Skoglund's "Ruby On Rails 4 Essential Training."  It is about 13hrs long and is the best rails intro that I have found online.  Located here: http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-4-Essential-Training/139989-2.html

If you are like me, you will end of watching that training about three times through, and then refer back to sections of the training videos multiple times.  After you get comfortable with that, head on over to www.codeschool.com and watch their courses: "Rails 4: Zombie Outlaws" and "Rails 4 Patterns."

Of course, before even digging into rails, you want to make sure you have a solid understanding of the ruby programming language.  Rails will make a lot more since once you put it into context: Rails is just ruby code.  Kevin Skoglund has an excellent training video on Ruby: http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-tutorials/essential-training/47905-2.html

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I'm surprised this issue hasn't been more addressed. I was hoping you could clarify a little more since I'm still confused. What do you mean by `@someVariableToPassToView = 33` if you were going to use the habits example above. I don't understand what `= 33` means?

Comment: updated my response above.  Please be sure to vote up and/or provide checkmark to my response if I helped you, and/or I guided you in the right direction.